# Can a flex box container be positioned absolutely

Tags: css, flexbox

Can one flex container(A) be positioned absolutely in front or behind of another flex container(B) and still maintain flex properties of its children?

My problem: When I assign a flex-container(B) to position:absolute, the children content inside lose the automatic flex properties. When I switch back to position:relative, flex works again. When container(B) is relative, I can't overlay on top of the other flex container(A) like I need.

Research:  Found everything on absolute positioning of children in parent flex containers (W3C and CSS tricks, etc), but nothing specific enough to flex containers being moved absolutely over another flex container (which makes me wonder if it's even possible!).  If so, I'll be rollin' in joy.

Ultimate Goal: Want to overlay one adjacent flex container over another with different z-indexes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Flex items* with absolute positioning will ignore flex properties. A *flex container* with absolute positioning is fine. Unless, of course, the container is also an item. You should post your code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: create a parent as absolute element. And its child with flex properties. Or just had relative positioning and apply z-index for the overlay container

Comment: relative positioning with z-index works like a charm (now have two methods) -thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we don't know how your original code looks like, here is a general layout with one *flex container* being absolute positioned on top of another.

To make the `position: absolute` element align as its sibling, I wrapped them both and gave the second `width: 100%`

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.a, .b {
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.a {
  background: red;
}
.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.wrap > div > div {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: green;
}
.wrap div div:first-child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="b">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Above code works perfect for the scenario I attempted.  Can you tell I'm new to flex? ( ;  Thanks

Comment: @RobertBepko `flexbox` is easy and complicated, so how to tell is somewhat not a straight answer. This article, [A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), is good. Read it, and then read it again, and still, when you think you know it, something comes up that does not behave as you once thought.

Comment: Thanks. That flexbox page is entirely useful. In hindsight, the part I was missing was the flex basis and width properties you clarified above. Without it, the row in my project narrowed upon selecting b to display:absolute (b in this case). Limitless possibilities ahead. Best!